Stability of 2 objects in uniform motion due to friction
When two objects are in relative motion, be it in relative translational motion or one rolling on another surface, sliding friction converges them to uniform motion thereby eliminating relative motion. It can be proved that when there's no external force F, uniform motion (no relative motion) is stable due to sliding friction as in the attached translational motion when F=0 and only friction f is present. All frictional forces to be considered are in the figure.

When there's an external force ($F>f ≠ 0$), is uniform motion (no relative motion) still stable? If so, how to prove it?

If static friction  force is greater than F  both move with same speed

@trula suppose F>f

"Is it possible?"
This is how you approach these problems. You set a scenario, here both blocks moving with the same acceleration, and find if the forces required to do so are compatible with the known laws of friction.
Given the friction force $f$ acting in equal and opposite measure on the two objects, you write the sum of forces as
$$\begin{aligned}
 \sum F_{\rm top} & = F - f \\
 \sum F_{\rm bottom} & = f 
\end{aligned}$$
and from Newton's second law, the above is related to the common (assumed) acceleration $a$ and each mass
$$\begin{aligned}
 \sum F_{\rm top} & = F - f = m _{\rm top}\; a\\
 \sum F_{\rm bot} & = f = m_{\rm bot}\; a
\end{aligned}$$
and the two equations above are solved for the required friction $f$ and the acceleration $a$.
$$ \begin{aligned}
  a &= \frac{1}{m_{\rm top} + m_{\rm bot}} F \\
  f & = \frac{m_{\rm bot}}{m_{\rm top} + m_{\rm bot}} F
\end{aligned}$$
So now the question becomes, in this scenario, is the above force $f$ compatible with friction?
But in your question, you did not mention if the objects are sliding on a frictionless horizontal plane in the presence of gravity, or they are floating in space in the absence of gravity.
For the second case, since there is no normal force between the bodies (absence of gravity) then the frictional force $f$ can only be zero, and thus, no the objects cannot move coherently.
For the first case, the normal force between the two objects is $N = m_{\rm top} g$, with $\mu$ the coefficient of friction, and thus the law of (dry) friction states
$$ f \le \mu N = \mu\, m_{\rm top}\, g$$
So the condition to make coherent movement possible is (after some manipulation)
$$ F \le \mu g \left( \frac{ m_{\rm top} ( m_{\rm top}+m_{\rm bot})}{ m_{\rm   bot}} \right) $$

thanks for the answer. All frictional forces are in the original figure, so let's ignore any frictional force from beneath the bottom block. But this question is about the stability of uniform motion, not the requirement of F etc.
